# Can't Seem to Insert CTE Into Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My cte run find, and gives me the numbers I expect, but I can't seem to insert the results into a table.  I did some research online, before posting, and the setup seems correct, based on what I've seen, but I must be missing some step somewhere, because this script doesn't work.  Can someone see something that I can't see?  I am on SQL Server 2008.

```
with cte as 
(
select 
       *, rn = row_number() over (partition by Credit_Line_NO order by REVIEW_FREQUENCY)
from TBL_FBNK_LIMIT_HIST
) 

(select CREDIT_LINE_NO
    ,LIMIT_CURRENCY
    ,(CAST(AVAIL_AMT AS DECIMAL(30,15)) * (CAST(SUBSTRING(CUSIP_NO,1,CHARINDEX('%',CUSIP_NO)-1) AS DECIMAL(30,15))/100))/(12/CAST(LEFT(SUBSTRING(REVIEW_FREQUENCY, CHARINDEX('M',review_frequency)+1,LEN(REVIEW_FREQUENCY)),2) AS DECIMAL)) AS AMOUNT
    ,REVIEW_FREQUENCY   
    ,CAST(LEFT(REVIEW_FREQUENCY, 8) AS DATE) AS STARTDATE
    ,CAST(EXPIRY_DATE AS DATE)  AS EXPIRY_DATE
    ,CAST(round((DATEDIFF(MONTH,cast(LEFT(REVIEW_FREQUENCY,8) as DATE),CAST(EXPIRY_DATE AS DATE)))/cast(LEFT(SUBSTRING  (REVIEW_FREQUENCY, CHARINDEX('M',review_frequency)+1,LEN(REVIEW_FREQUENCY)),2) as decimal)+0.4,0) AS INTEGER) AS FREQUENCY  
    ,CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, (rn-1)* LEFT((SUBSTRING(REVIEW_FREQUENCY, CHARINDEX('M',review_frequency)+1,LEN(REVIEW_FREQUENCY))),2),LEFT(REVIEW_FREQUENCY, 8)) AS DATE) AS EFFECTIVESTARTDATE
FROM cte
WHERE AVAIL_AMT NOT LIKE '%]%'
    AND CUSIP_NO IS NOT NULL  
    AND CUSIP_NO <> '0' 
    AND AVAIL_AMT <> '0'
    AND AVAIL_AMT IS NOT NULL)
INSERT TBL_FBNK_LIMIT_HIST_TRANS_SPLIT (CREDIT_LINE_NO,LIMIT_CURRENCY,AMOUNT,REVIEW_FREQUENCY,START_DATE,EXPIRY_DATE,FREQUENCY,AsOfDate,EFFECTIVESTARTDATE)
Select CREDIT_LINE_NO,LIMIT_CURRENCY,AMOUNT,REVIEW_FREQUENCY,START_DATE,EXPIRY_DATE,FREQUENCY,AsOfDate,EFFECTIVESTARTDATE
From cte
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Doesn't work"? You have enough reputation to know that isn't helpful.

Comment: You've stuffed an entire new parenthesized `SELECT` query after your CTE but before your `INSERT`. Either you want that to be a second CTE (`,other_cte AS (` or you wanted to do something else entirely, and it's not clear what from the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not really using the cute in the insert. Try it like:

```
with cte as 
(
select 
       *, rn = row_number() over (partition by Credit_Line_NO order by REVIEW_FREQUENCY)
from TBL_FBNK_LIMIT_HIST
), 
cte2 as 
(select CREDIT_LINE_NO
    ,LIMIT_CURRENCY
    ,(CAST(AVAIL_AMT AS DECIMAL(30,15)) * (CAST(SUBSTRING(CUSIP_NO,1,CHARINDEX('%',CUSIP_NO)-1) AS DECIMAL(30,15))/100))/(12/CAST(LEFT(SUBSTRING(REVIEW_FREQUENCY, CHARINDEX('M',review_frequency)+1,LEN(REVIEW_FREQUENCY)),2) AS DECIMAL)) AS AMOUNT
    ,REVIEW_FREQUENCY   
    ,CAST(LEFT(REVIEW_FREQUENCY, 8) AS DATE) AS STARTDATE
    ,CAST(EXPIRY_DATE AS DATE)  AS EXPIRY_DATE
    ,CAST(round((DATEDIFF(MONTH,cast(LEFT(REVIEW_FREQUENCY,8) as DATE),CAST(EXPIRY_DATE AS DATE)))/cast(LEFT(SUBSTRING  (REVIEW_FREQUENCY, CHARINDEX('M',review_frequency)+1,LEN(REVIEW_FREQUENCY)),2) as decimal)+0.4,0) AS INTEGER) AS FREQUENCY  
    ,CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, (rn-1)* LEFT((SUBSTRING(REVIEW_FREQUENCY, CHARINDEX('M',review_frequency)+1,LEN(REVIEW_FREQUENCY))),2),LEFT(REVIEW_FREQUENCY, 8)) AS DATE) AS EFFECTIVESTARTDATE
FROM cte
WHERE AVAIL_AMT NOT LIKE '%]%'
    AND CUSIP_NO IS NOT NULL  
    AND CUSIP_NO <> '0' 
    AND AVAIL_AMT <> '0'
    AND AVAIL_AMT IS NOT NULL)
INSERT TBL_FBNK_LIMIT_HIST_TRANS_SPLIT (CREDIT_LINE_NO,LIMIT_CURRENCY,AMOUNT,REVIEW_FREQUENCY,START_DATE,EXPIRY_DATE,FREQUENCY,AsOfDate,EFFECTIVESTARTDATE)
Select CREDIT_LINE_NO,LIMIT_CURRENCY,AMOUNT,REVIEW_FREQUENCY,START_DATE,EXPIRY_DATE,FREQUENCY,AsOfDate,EFFECTIVESTARTDATE
From cte2;
```

Code looks like redundant but at least it would work the way you think it should.

Comment: @ Cetin Basoz, that worked!  I knew it was something like that!  Thanks a bunch!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the CTE in the statement for which it is defined. In your case, you have the CTE definition, and a SELECT statement that reads the CTE.

Then, you have a totally separate statement which attempts to read the CTE again for the INSERT. This is not permitted, because the CTE does not exist in the second query's context. So, from the perspective of your INSERT statement, the CTE does not exist. I'm sure you're getting this message:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line [x] Invalid object name 'cte'.

Get rid of the SELECT statement and replace it with your INSERT.
Alternatively, if you must have the SELECT statement used in both the SELECT and INSERT statements, a CTE may not be appropriate for the use case, or you will need to include the CTE definition for both the SELECT and INSERT.

Answer (score -1):

It should be working fine unless those columns are not in TBL_FBNK_LIMIT_HIST_TRANS_SPLIT or the data types do not match.

That select in the middle is not part of the insert.

```
INSERT TBL_FBNK_LIMIT_HIST_TRANS_SPLIT 
       (CREDIT_LINE_NO, LIMIT_CURRENCY, AMOUNT, REVIEW_FREQUENCY, START_DATE, EXPIRY_DATE, FREQUENCY, AsOfDate, EFFECTIVESTARTDATE)
Select  CREDIT_LINE_NO, LIMIT_CURRENCY, AMOUNT, REVIEW_FREQUENCY, START_DATE, EXPIRY_DATE, FREQUENCY, AsOfDate, EFFECTIVESTARTDATE
From cte
```

Comment: @PittsburghDBA So it is reading the CTE.  It is still not part of the insert.

Comment: That sentence may be semantically correct, but your sentence of "It should be working fine" is not true, because there is no CTE on the INSERT, so it has no chance to work fine, regardless of data types or other non-relevant matters.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA Not going to argue with you

Comment: I'm not trying to argue; I'm just opposed to answers that hit so fast without an analysis. There is no conceivable way to have this: Statement1: (CTE/SELECT) Statement2: (INSERT/SELECT FROM non-existent CTE), and claim that Statement2 should work.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA Still not going to argue with you.  *That* is a valid statement if columns in the insert match the CTE.

Comment: No it is not! It still won't work, regardless - BECAUSE (as written) THE INSERT STATEMENT HAS NO ACCESS TO THE CTE

Comment: @PittsburghDBA Let it go. If the columns of the cte match insert then *that* which is posted in my answer is a valid statement.  In the question a select spoiling the CTE is a different issue.

Comment: I think the point is being missed. The SELECT is not 'spoiling' anything; it's not just a random SELECT. That SELECT is reading from the CTE. If it was just a random SELECT, the entire statement is invalid, because you cannot declare a CTE and not read from it in the same statement. The error in that case would be >'Common table expression defined but not used.'

Comment: @PittsburghDBA I don't care to discuss with you further and I don't need tutoring from you on CTE.